# Angular infdig Exception After Save Credential Prompt on Safari Mobile

Tags: angularjs, mobile-safari

I am encountering the following AngularJS exception every time the Safari Mobile save credentials prompt appears:

```
[Error] Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.   Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js:14271:31
$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js:14493:31
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js:21402:29
eventHandler@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js:3011:25
    (anonymous function) (angular.js, line 11598)
    (anonymous function) (angular.js, line 8548)
    $apply (angular.js, line 14495)
    (anonymous function) (angular.js, line 21402)
    eventHandler (angular.js, line 3011)
[Error] Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.  Aborting! (angular.js, line 14271)
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

I have been able to replicate the issue in this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/tkGGtxGRnWrfQUprDqjb. It appears to be a result of the way the save credentials prompt has been implemented in Safari Mobile since I have not seen it in any other browser. Also, if I save credentials so that the prompt does not appear, I do not get the error. The page appears to function normally after the exception so, I could trap this exception and ignore it but I'm hoping there's a better solution out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to avoid this exception was to reload the page after the ajax call for the login returned. Making this change also provides more support for other browser password managers since some require a page refresh to be triggered. To trigger a page change and reload from within my angular controller I used the following code:

```
$window.location.href = '#/mypage';
$window.location.reload();
```